# Non-consecutively repeating array of integers

Tags: c#, arrays, random

I am trying to generate a non-consecutively repeating array of integers. What I have so far works pretty well except that it will occasionally generate a set of double 0's. My questions are:

1. How can I stop that
2. There has to be a better way to do this right? It's pretty ugly.

I am grateful for any insights you can share.

This is the code:

```
        int[] randInts = new int[20];

        Random rand = new Random();


        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            randInts[i] = rand.Next(0, 8);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
        {
            if (randInts[i] == randInts[i - 1] && randInts[i] < 8 && randInts[i] > 0)
            {
                randInts[i]--;
            }

            else if (randInts[i] == randInts[i - 1] && randInts[i] > 0)
            {
                randInts[i]++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public IEnumerable<int> NonConsecutiveRepeatingRandomValues(int upperBound)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int prev = -1;
    while(true)
    {
        int value = prev;
        while (value == prev)
            value = rand.Next(upperBound);
        yield return value;
    }
}
```

And then to get exactly 20 values (and not loop forever) call it like this:

```
var randInts = NonConsecutiveRepeatingRandomValues(8).Take(20).ToArray();
```

But only use the `ToArray()` call if you *really* need an array. You'd be surprised how often you can get by without it.

Comment: Side note: when using don't forget to move `rand` out in static variable to avoid identical sequences...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov This is one of those few things VB.Net actually does better... VB has `Shared` instead of `static`, but also has a `Static` keyword you can use to declare a variable in a method to get this exact behavior (it's even thread-safe). Thankfully, things should be fairly safe in the method for this question, since it uses the same instance for the entire sequence -- but ideally, yes, you would keep it even longer. Or, even better, use a cryptographic PRNG.

Comment: The upper bound is actually `upperBound - 1` in `value = rand.Next(upperBound);`. Should be documented :)

Answer (score 1):

How about when you roll the same number as you did last time, you just roll again?

```
int[] randInts = new int[20];
Random rand = new Random();

int lastVal = -1;
int val = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{   
    while (val == lastVal)
        val = rand.Next(0, 8);  

    randInts[i] = val;
    lastVal = val;
}
```

Of course you will be generating more random numbers than you need but the performance loss wont be significant.